# Best way to manage multiple php includes?

Tags: php, html

With my current workflow, when I need to add a new CSS sheet or a new script to a 10 pages website, I need to do this 10 times. Same story if I need to rename one item in my navigation menu, or correct a typo in the footer.

That made me realize that I need to start learning PHP to handle that via includes, echo, etc.

Therefore my question is the following: is there a best practice to do this? (I guess this is relatively easy to implement a `< ?php include 'header.php'; ?>` and a `< ?php include 'footer'; ?>` but can become quickly messy when it comes to dealing with unique page title and descriptions, etc.

What are your suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: "Best way to manage meta tags, scripts, headers and footers in php" -- `php include` is the best way to do that.

Comment: "but can become quickly messy when it comes to dealing with unique page title and descriptions, etc." -- Go with a CMS like WordPress and customise it according to what you need. But as you might have guessed, you will need to know PHP to customised WordPress themes, templates and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your building not object style PHP website using `require_once` seems just the proper way to achieve your goal. It's better than include because `require` spread all errors and `_once` only include it once (Even if there is an inclusion of the same file deeper in the including tree) :)

Elsewhere [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) is library that handle exactly this :)